# X axis label overlapping in vega lite chart

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I want to create chart like time table structure chart in Vega lite but facing issue while x axis label is overlapping.
I want x axis label not overlap it must break if it going out of rect box size and just display below it .
[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-fsyUXYDbhrbp2OkwSQBJc0lOXXoAEd+EBepjHqNhexIoIR3MSwDkEOs4MMm5KxtHRJ3YEcvy0kAwNnCorBguDnUBW82O6c0GKAA)

i want like this label of x axis----

```
                     Ravi kumar
                     sharma pcm 
                    (chemistry-sec
                     tion a,b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "width": 600,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Day": "Monday",
        "Teacher Name": ["Ravi kumar","sharma pcm","(chemistry-section a,b)"],
        "Date": "2023/12/01",
        "Count": 10,
        "color_code": "#27AE60"
      },
      {
        "Day": "Tuesday",
        "Teacher Name": "Sandep kumar sharma pcm (chemistry-section c,d",
        "Date": "2023/11/01",
        "Count": 1,
        "color_code": "#FED380"
      },
      {
        "Day": "Wednesday",
        "Teacher Name": "Manoj(PHYSICAL)",
        "Date": "2023/10/15",
        "Count": 24,
        "color_code": "#FB9273"
      },
      {
        "Day": "Thuresday",
        "Teacher Name": "Amit(Eng)",
        "Date": "2024/02/01",
        "Count": 29,
        "color_code": "#F8696B"
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rect"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Day", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"grid": false}},
        "x": {
          "field": "Teacher Name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "orient": "top",
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelAngle": 0, "labelPadding":30
          }
        },
        "color": {"field": "color_code", "legend": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Day", "type": "nominal"},
        "x": {
          "field": "Teacher Name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"orient": "top"}
        },
        "text": {"field": "Count", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axis": {"grid": true, "tickBand": "extent"}}
}
```

Comment: it look good,but issue is that is any x-axis label is to long then label display over the chart,  how we can make dynamic value of labelPadding such that it automatically adjust as per the large text value.i did not want make it static.

Comment: A better way is to switch your axes - make x your y and y your x. Long labels are best on a Y axis.

Comment: yes it good, but i want as usual axis, i want to know is there any calculation or formula can be applicable which calculate the legend padding on the basis of datum(Teacher Name).length

Comment: There is a technique on Giammaria's GitHub you can use for text calculations. https://github.com/Giammaria/Vega-Lite-Techniques

Comment: Congrats. You passed Ron for powerquery tag